# Outputting SQL queries with Javascript, PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to have a form, which when submitted returns the output from a simple SQL query onto the page without needing to be reloaded (AJAX). I can get simple outputs to work but when I use the PHP for the SQL query nothing is returned. Any help would be much appreciated. I also can't find anyway to check what is wrong with my Javascript/Php.

Pretty new to web development so apologies if this is trivial. All previously found solutions haven't worked

My Code;

a1.php

```
<script src='../js/scriptget.js'></script>
<form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login</legend>
                Username:<br>
                <input type="text" name="myusername" placeholder="Username">
                <br>
                Password:<br>
                <input type="text" name="mypassword" placeholder="Password">
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick='return getAccount();'>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

scriptget.js

```
function getAccount(){

var phpOut = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'submitInjection.php',
    data: 'myusername=billsmith&mypassword=password'
});


drawOutput('hello');
return false;
}



function drawOutput(responseText){
    var container = document.getElementById('output2');
    container.innerHTML = responseText;
}
```

submitinjection.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; //Host Name
$username="root"; // MySql Username
$password="root"; // Mysql Password
$db_name="Honours2"; //Database Name
$tbl_name="Users"; // Table Name

// Connect to server and select database
$conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("Cannot Connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("Cannot select DB");


// User and Password sent from form

$myusername = $_GET['myusername'];
$mypassword = $_GET['mypassword'];

/**
Protect MYSQL INJECTION
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

*/

$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM $tbl_name 
        WHERE username = '$myusername'
        AND password = '$mypassword'
        ";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

/*  echo $sql; */

if (!$result){
    die('Invalid Query: ' . mysql_error() . $sql);
}

if ($result){
    echo($sql);
}

/*  var_dump($result); */   

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['username'];
    echo ": ";
    echo $row['balance'];
}

mysql_free_result($result);

$conn->close(); 

?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do hope you're not putting real passwords through that in plaintext...

Comment: Add a `success` function / handler to your ajax call to process the results.

Comment: In the PHP file you `echo` the results you want, then in JS AJAX you use a `success` function with a variable for the results.

Comment: @ArtOfCode No this is for testing purposes only, don't worry haha.

Comment: @jeroen I'm a bit new to this, would you be able to tell me how to do it?

Comment: @jeroen is what I'm doing not already echo'ing the results? the php works fine if I don't use ajax and just load a new page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to process the results of your ajax call in for example a `success` function. You can also use things like `.done()` or `$.when().then()`, check the jQuery manual for that.

A simple example using a `success` function:

```
var phpOut = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'submitInjection.php',
    data: 'myusername=billsmith&mypassword=password',
    success: function(data_returned) {
        alert(data_returned);
        // or
        $('#output2').html(data_returned);
    }
});
```

Some additional notes:

- Don't use `GET` to send sensitive information to the server, use `POST` instead;
- Don't store plain-text passwords, salt and hash them;
- The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you should switch to `mysqli_*` or PDO where you can use prepared statements to avoid sql injection, making escaping unnecessary.

Comment: I'm trying to do this now, is there a way to check where things are going wrong? An error log of some kind

Comment: @Mejaniks The javascript console of your browsers development tools would be a good place to start.

Comment: I'm currently running:

function getAccount(){
 var data_returned;
 console.log('hello');
 var phpOut = $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'submitInjection.php',
     data: 'myusername=billsmith&mypassword=password',
     success: function(data_returned){
      drawOutput(data_returned);
     }
 });
}


with no avail, I'm not even getting any output on the console, is there something super obvious I'm missing?

Comment: @Mejaniks If you have a `console.log` call, you are getting output. Press F12. What browser?

Comment: @ArtOfCode I'm using Chrome

Comment: @ArtOfCode okay it turns out that the console output is coming through, but only flashing for a microsecond then disappearing

Comment: @ArtOfCode Wasn't returning false, console works fine now, thanks

Comment: @Mejaniks Instead of an inline click event handler, you should catch the form submit event in javascript and prevent the default action: `$('form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); // rest of code }`. That way you can separate your javascript from your html.

Comment: @jeroen Using the previous method I've managed to get it almost working, it's returning the SQL Query instead of the output from it:

Code:

function getAccount(){
 var data_returned;
 console.log('hello');
 var phpOut = $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'submitInjection.php',
     data: 'myusername=billsmith&mypassword=password',
     success: function(data_returned){
      drawOutput(data_returned);
     }
 });
 return false;
}
 


function drawOutput(responseText){
/*  alert(data_returned); */
 var container = document.getElementById('output2');
 container.innerHTML = responseText;
}

Comment: @jeroen Haha sorry I had just forgotten to take it out the PHp when I was testing, thanks so much guys

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `success` callback function to your `$.ajax()` call. That callback function should call your 'drawOutput' function with response it gets as a parameter. Something like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    drawOutput(data);
}
```